# Using Solve but getting no output

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a model using a constant-elasticity-of-substitution production function, but when I try to solve the first order conditions, I just keep getting back what I typed.

```
Solve[-i - q + p s^(-1 + a) (1 + s^a)^(-1 + 1/a) - t == 0, s]
```

> ```
> Solve[-i - q + p s^(-1 + a) (1 + s^a)^(-1 + 1/a) - t == 0, s]
> ```

Any help on how to tackle this problem would be great.

Comment: I get the message "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>".

Comment: You should be aware that there are many apparently simple equations with solutions that are not expressible in closed form. One such example is `Solve[Cos[x]==x,x]`. On the other hand, `Solve[Cos[x]==x,x,Reals]` produces a useful result. Thus, it's nice to now if your variables and parameters satisfy any useful assumptions. Lacking a symbolic expression, perhaps you'd be happy with a function that produces an estimate for `s` as a function of the input parameters?

Comment: For `a=1` the solution is easy, but for arbitrary `a` it isn't. So information about `a` would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that mimics the by-hand method.  The idea is to replace common subexpressions by symbols until it gets to the point where `Solve` will work.  In some places I'm assuming that quantities are real and positive.

```
eqn = -i - q + p s^(-1 + a) (1 + s^a)^(-1 + 1/a) - t == 0 /.  s -> u^(1/a) // PowerExpand
eqn = eqn /. a -> 1/(1 - r) // Simplify
(*
  -i - q - t + p u^((-1 + a)/a) (1 + u)^(-1 + 1/a) == 0
  i + q + t == p (u/(1 + u))^r
*)

sol = s -> u^a /. Solve[eqn, u] /. r -> (a - 1)/a // Simplify
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
(*  {s -> (1/(-1 + ((i + q + t)/p)^(a/(1 - a))))^a}  *)
```

Comment: Very nice. Wish I had thunk of that.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Well, thanks. I don't know what it says that I had to solve it by hand to figure out how to help *M* get to the answer. Seems backwards. Devendra showed an example at WTC that gave me the idea that one could coax `Solve` over the hill in this way. In case he likes feedback. :)

Comment: I sent a link to him (Devendra).